# How to send keystroke with shift modifier?

Tags: digispark

This is a bit of a newbie question, but here it goes anyway. So basically I want to send a keystroke using the DigiKeyboard library, but with shift held down. I looked through the code and saw this comment in scancode-ascii-table.h:

```
//Format: most signifficant bit indicates if scan code should be sent with shift modifier
remaining 7 bits are to be used as scan code number.
```

I dont really understand where to specify this, whether it's when you call the sendKeyStroke function, or somewhere in the code. Help appreciated.

Comment: what does `most significant bit` mean to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used this library, but in the header file there are this constants for modifiers:

```
#define MOD_CONTROL_LEFT    (1<<0)
#define MOD_SHIFT_LEFT      (1<<1)
#define MOD_ALT_LEFT        (1<<2)
#define MOD_GUI_LEFT        (1<<3)
#define MOD_CONTROL_RIGHT   (1<<4)
#define MOD_SHIFT_RIGHT     (1<<5)
#define MOD_ALT_RIGHT       (1<<6)
#define MOD_GUI_RIGHT       (1<<7)
```

and a function

```
void sendKeyStroke(byte keyStroke, byte modifiers)
```

so I would use this to send a key with Shift like this

```
sendKeyStroke(KEY_F2, MOD_SHIFT_LEFT);
```

Comment: Oooooh thank you! That works perfectly!